# Method Override and why output is zero?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

```
public class Test {
    // one class needs to have a main() method
    public static class Parent {
        int i = 1000;

        Parent() {
            test();
        }

        public void test() {
            System.out.println("Parent: " + i);
        }
    }

    public static class MyClass extends Parent {
        int i = 100;

        MyClass() {
            super();
        }

        public void test() {
            System.out.println("MyClass: " + i);
        }

    }

    // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
        myObject.test();
    }
}
```

[image: Code and output is here]

Comment: post code as text, not image

Comment: code is in the image link.

Comment: I have no idea why it was easier for you to create images and upload them for those few lines of code and output. Just post the code here as text.

Comment: @ShanHtet that's exactly why I said "post code as text, not image"

Comment: Don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is somewhat unexpected (as your question already suggests) but can be explained by Java's initialization order:

The initialization order in general is the following:

1. Static blocks of the super class
2. Static blocks of the class
3. Non-static blocks of the super class
4. Constructor of the super class
5. Non-static blocks of the class
6. Constructor of the class

In your example `Parent` is a super class of `MyClass` and `MyClass` overrides `Parent`'s `test()` method. That is in the constructor of `Parent` the `test()` implementation of `MyClass` is executed. As this is called before the non-static blocks of `MyClass` (i.e. `int i = 100;`) have been executed, `i` has it's default value 0 in the first call to `test`. In the second call to `test()` `i` has been initialized and thus has it's value of 100 assigned.

If you're wondering why `i` is 0 and not 1000. This is because class fields are not overridden when creating a sub-class with identically named fields. That is in `MyClass.test()` always the field `MyClass.i` is used.